# Continuous even functions closed and dense

Tags: real-analysis, even-and-odd-functions, function-spaces

Let $C_e([−1,1],R)$ denote the set of even functions in $C([−1,1],R)$

(a) Show $C_e$ is closed and not dense in $C$.

(b) show the even polynomials are dense in $C_e$, but not in $C$.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, forgive me if this is trivial, but what is the topology/metric/norm we're working with?

Comment: I'm not really even sure where to start, but i think this is sup norm

Answer (score 1):

**To show that $C_e$ is closed in $C$:**

We need to show that if we have a convergent sequence of even continuous functions $f_n$ with limit $f \in C$, then $f \in C_e$. (This is by an equivalent definition of closed sets in metric spaces).

Suppose not for contradiction. Then there exists a convergent sequence of even continuous functions $f_n$ with limit $f \in C$, but $f \notin C_e$.

Then $f_n(x) = f_n(-x)$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$, for all $n$ and there exists an $x \in [-1,1]$ such that $f(x) \neq f(-x)$. So there exist $\epsilon >0$ and $x \in [-1,1]$ such that $|f(x) - f(-x)| = \epsilon$. **(1)**

Since $f_n$ converges to $f$ under the sup norm, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $\sup_\limits{x\in [ -1,1]} |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon} {2}$, so for all $x \in [-1,1]$, $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon} {2}$ .

Additionally, for all $x \in [-1,1]$, $|f_n(-x) - f(-x)| < \frac{\epsilon} {2}$.

Since $f_n(x) = f_n(-x)$ for all $x$ and $n$, $|f_n(x) -f_n(-x)| = 0$.

Hence for all $x \in [-1,1]$, $$|f(x) - f(-x)| \leq |f(x) - f_n(x)| +|f_n(x) - f_n(-x)| +|f_n(-x) - f(-x)| $$

$$< \frac{\epsilon} {2} + 0 + \frac{\epsilon} {2} = \epsilon$$

This is a contradiction with **(1)**.

Therefore the limit $f$ must be even. So the set of even continuous functions is closed in $C$.

**To show $C_e$ is not dense in $C$:**

We need to show that there exists a continuous function which is not even and is not the limit of any sequence of even continuous functions.

Take the function $x$. Clearly $x$ is not even and is continuous.

Suppose there is a sequence of even continuous functions $g_n$ that converges in the sup norm to $x$. Hence $g_n$ converges uniformly to $x$ on $[-1,1]$.

Therefore, by the properties of uniform convergence and the Riemann integral, $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \int_{-1}^1 g_n = \int_{-1}^1 \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} g_n =\int_{-1}^1 x = 0 $

Since all the $g_n$ are even, $\int_{-1}^1 g_n = 2 \int_{0}^1 g_n $ for all $n$.

Since the function is continuous and on a compact interval, all these Riemann integrals are defined, so  $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^1 g_n = \frac{1}{2} \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \int_{-1}^1 g_n = 0$ .

Take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{4}$, then there exists an $N_1$ such that for all $n \geq N$,  $|\int_{0}^1 g_n| < \frac{1}{4}$.

Also, since $g_n$ converges uniformly to $x$ on $[0,1]$,  $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^1 g_n = \int_{0}^1 x = \frac{1}{2}$. So there exists an $N_2$ such that for all $n \geq N$,  $|\int_{0}^1 g_n -\frac{1}{2}| < \frac{1}{4}$.

Let $N :=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$. Then for all $n\geq N$, $$\frac{1}{2} = |\int_{0}^1 g_n + \frac{1}{2}- \int_{0}^1 g_n | \leq|\int_{0}^1 g_n |+ |\int_{0}^1 g_n -\frac{1}{2}| < \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{4} =\frac{1}{2}$$

which is a contradiction.

Try to do something similar with the second part.

Comment: thanks! this was so helpful

Comment: @user237690 If it helped, you can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: To show that the function $g(x)=x$ is not in $\overline C_e$ in the $\sup$ norm it suffices to observe that for any $f\in C_e$ we have $\|f-g\|\ge \max(|f(1)-g(1)|,|f(-1)-g(-1)|)=\max (|f(1)-1|,|f(1)+1|)\ge 1$ because for any $r\in \Bbb R$ we have $\max (|r-1|,|r+1|)\ge 1.$

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something but the answer seems longer than necessary. For the closure: if $f_n \to f$ uniformly, then $f_n \to f$ pointwise as well. So, given any $x$, we have $$f(x) = \lim_n f_n(x) = \lim_n f_n(-x) = f(-x)$$ and so, $f \in C_e$. Once we have that $C_e$ is closed and not all of $C$, it follows that $C_e$ is not dense in $C$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that convergence in this metric is simply uniform convergence.

**$\pmb C_e$ is closed.**

Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence in $C_e$ that has a limit $f \in C$. We show that $f \in C_e$. To this end, let $x \in [-1, 1]$ be arbitrary. Then, since $f_n \to f$ uniformly, we know that $f_n \to f$ pointwise as well. Thus, $$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(-x) = f(-x),$$
where the middle equality follows since $f_n \in C_e$. Thus, we have shown that $f \in C_e$.

**$\pmb C_e$ is not dense.**

Since $C_e$ is closed and not all of $C$, we have $\overline{C_e} = C_e \neq C$ and thus, $C_e$ is not dense in $C$.
(Recall that $C_e$ being dense in $C$ would mean that $\overline{C_e} = C$.)

**Even polynomials are dense in $\pmb C_e$**

Let $f : [-1, 1] \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous even function. Define $g : [0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ by $$g(x) = f(\sqrt{x}).$$ Then, $g$ is continuous and thus, there exists a sequence $(p_n)_n$ of polynomial functions such that $p_n \to g$ uniformly on $[0, 1]$. (Existence follows from the Weierstrass approximation theorem.)

Consider the sequence $(q_n)_n$ defined as $$q_n(x) = p_n(x^2).$$ Thus, $(q_n)_n$ is a sequence of even polynomials. Moreover, note that
\begin{align}
\|q_n - f\| &= \sup_{x \in [-1, 1]} |p_n(x^2) - g(x^2)| \\
&= \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |p_n(x) - g(x)| = \|p_n - g\| \to 0.
\end{align}
Thus, $q_n \to f$ uniformly.

**Even polynomials are not dense in $\pmb C$.**

Obvious since even $C_e$ is not dense in $C$.