# Uniform approximation of continuous function by even polynomials

Tags: real-analysis

If f is a continuous function on [a,b], I want to show whether there exists sequence of even polynomials which converges uniformly to f.
I was checking this problem in StackExchange.
The above statement was proved here [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693629/uniform-approximation-by-even-polynomial.\](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693629/uniform-approximation-by-even-polynomial.%5C)

But here [Continuous even functions closed and dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1265865/continuous-even-functions-closed-and-dense/1266168)  one example of function was produced which can't be approximated uniformly by even polynomials.
Both the solutions seem right to me. I am confused now.
Am I missing something ? Please help me.

Comment: On $[-1,1]$ only even continuous functions can be approximated by even polynomials. But on $[0,1]$ any continuous function can be approximated by even polynomials.

Comment: ok. I thought the statement is true for any closed interval [a,b]. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that even polynomials are dense on $[0,1]$ or on any other interval contained in the positive semi axis or in the negative semi axis but they cannot be dense on a symmetric interval like $[-1,1]$ since any combination of even functions would be even and, for example an odd function clearly cannot be approximated uniformly.

Comment: Thank you. Is the same thing true for odd polynomials also?

Comment: Sure. If all polynomials are dense and even polynomials are dense, then also odd polynomials (which are difference of those) are also dense (but again, not on an interval containing zero).

Comment: Odd polynomials are not dense in $C[0,1]$  since they must vanish at $0$

Comment: @YuvalPeres You are right. My previous comment about odd polynomials was incorrect. I do not know if odd polynomials are dense in intervals like $[a,b]$ with $0<a<b$, but my guess is that they are.

Comment: They certainly, are, since for $0<a<b$  such functions can be extended to odd functions $f$ on $[-b,b]$. Given  polynomial approximations $f_n$ of $f$ on $[-b,b]$,   the odd polynomials $(f_n(x)-f_n(-x))/2$ will converge uniformly on $[-b,b]$ to $f$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying!